# show timestamp on a circle

Tags: ios, swift, math, geometry

I want to show a certain period between to timestamps on a circle, using swift. (cfr screenshot)

[image]

I have this piece of code that show the time between 12:00 till 18:00

```
let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI) 
let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width,bounds.height)
let arcWidth: CGFloat = 5

let startAngle2: CGFloat = 3 * π / 2
let endAngle2: CGFloat = π / 2

 let path2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2 - arcWidth / 2, startAngle: startAngle2, endAngle: endAngle2, clockwise: true)
 path2.lineWidth = arcWidth
 strokeColer2.setStroke()
 path2.stroke()
```

What I need to know now is a function or calculation that gives me the start and end angle. If anyone has some suggestions, please let me know !

Answer (score 1):

It's just linear, with 12 hours = 2π radians, or 1 hour = π/6. Maths convention is anti-clockwise with 3 o'clock = 0 angle. Thus 12/0 = π/2, 3 = 0, 6 = -π/2, 9 = -π (or +π), so

`angle = (3 - hour % 12) * π / 6`

## Update

OP asks for hours:minutes example. I've added types.

```
let integerHours = 17
let minutes = 12
var fractionalHours = CGFloat(integerHours) + CGFloat(minutes) / 60
fractionalHours = fmod(fractionalHours, 12)
let angle = (3 - fractionalHours) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 6
```

Comment: Can you maybe give me the formula for 17:12 ?